# one real analysis problem to prove the existence of a sequence and limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

**Question:** Suppose that S is a nonempty subset of R that is bounded above and put s = sup S.Show that there is a sequence (xn) such that xn ∈ S for all n and lim as n apporaches infinity  xn = s.

Hi, I am a beginner for real analysis, the question about is the one that I am trying to do on my own, but I don't know how to analyze or solve it after I write the definitions out.

What I am thinking is that,

**Given**:  S is a non-empty subset of R that is bounded above and s equals to the sup A

**Prove**: <1> there is a sequence (xn) such that xn belongs to s for all n,
<2> limit of xn as n approaches to infinity is s

Thoughts: since S is a nonempty subset of R that is bounded above, then there exists a number t such that t is greater or equal to s for all s belongs to S, so we know t is an upper bound of s. 
Since s = sup S, then s is the least upper bound of S. since t is an upper bound for S, and s is the least upper bound, then t is also greater or equal to sup S. For the limit part, according to the definition of limit, we can write that |an-s|< epsilon.

I stop here because I don't how to do the following steps, I don't know how to use the information that I have so far to explain this questions.

Any help will be super appreciated

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $s= \sup S$. We know that:
$$
\text{ for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is $x\in S$ such that $s-\varepsilon < x$}.
$$
Thus for each $n>0$ you can choose $x_n\in S$ such that 
$$
s - \frac 1 n < x_n.
$$
Clearly, then, $s - \frac 1 n < x_n\le s$ for all $n>0$, so  $\lim_n x_n$ exists and equals $s$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Are you just pick ε to be (1/n) randomly?

Comment: Well, not "randomly", but yes there are (uncountably!) many other possibilities. All that's required is a sequence of positive numbers $(\varepsilon_n)_{n>0}$ that converges to 0. The simplest possible choice is $\varepsilon_n = 1/n$.

Comment: That make senses. Will we always want the positive numbers (ε n ) n>0 to converge to 0? Or it will be different in different cases?

Comment: I'm not sure what other "cases" or situations "always" refers to. For this problem, Yes: If  $(\varepsilon_n)$ doesn't converge, or converges to something nonzero, then the $x_n$ don't get "squeezed" and you can't conclude that $(x_n)\to \sup S$.

Comment: Anyway, you should upvote any of these answers you found helpful, and/or declare one "correct".

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Forgive me for asking another maybe silly question. I understand that s−1/n <x n ≤s  for all n>0, but from here, how did you conclude that the limit exists and it equals to s? My thought is that  s−1/n <x n ≤s  for all n>0 can only show that s is the upper bound for xn. Can we conclude xn is converges to s from this inequality?

Comment: It's because of the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem). The statement of it in the link I just gave is in terms of real functions, but it's true for sequences too. Here, the upper bounding sequence is constantly $s$. It's very easy to show that $x_n\to s$: Suppose $e>0$. There is $N>0$ s.t. $1/N<e$. Thus, if $n\ge N$ then $1/n<e$, so $s-e < s-1/n < x_n \le s$, so $|s-x_n| = s-x_n <e$. // Notice: here, it helps that $(\varepsilon_n)$ is decreasing: this proof is simple because of that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Put $s=\sup S$. If $s\in S$, define $x_n\equiv s$ and we are done.

Otherwise $s\notin S$. For each positive integer $n$, select $x_n\in S$ with $x_n\in (s-\frac1n,s)$ (why is this possible?). Then by construction $x_n \to s$ and each $x_n\in S$.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternating definition for $\sup$ will be useful here,  $s=\sup S$ iff 1) $s$ is an upper bound of $S$ and 2) for any $\epsilon>0$, $s-\epsilon$ is NOT an upper bound of $S$. (Try prove it using your definition)

Using above statement, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $s-\frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound of $s$, which means $\exists x_n\in S$, such that $x_n>s-\frac{1}{n}$. Also since $s$ is an upper bound of $S$, $x_n\le s$. Hence we have $$s-\frac{1}{n}<x_n\le s,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Can you continue here to justify $x_n\to s$?

Comment: Do we need to prove that x n ∈S is true? From my understanding, we are suppose to prove x n ∈S true and prove the limit. Do I misunderstand this question?

Answer (score 0):

Let $s=\sup S$.

We know that:

$\forall ε>0 \;\exists x∈S/\;s−ε<x \;$(By definition of supremum)

$\Rightarrow$ Given $ε_{1} = 1\gt0,\,\exists x_{1}\in S/ s-1\lt x_{1}\le s \;$(By def. of sup)

And

$\Rightarrow$ Given $ε_{2} = \frac{1}{2}\gt0,\,\exists x_{2}\in S/ s-\frac{1}{2}\lt x_{2}\le s \;$(By def. of sup)

And

$\Rightarrow$ Given $ε_{3} = \frac{1}{3}\gt0,\,\exists x_{3}\in S/ s-\frac{1}{3}\lt x_{3}\le s \;$(By def. of sup)

In an iterative way:

$\Rightarrow$ Given $ε_{m} = \frac{1}{m}\gt0,\,\exists x_{m}\in S/ s-\frac{1}{m}\lt x_{m}\le s,\, m\in \mathbb{N},\;$(By def. of sup)

Then, choosing all $x_{m}$ and forming the sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$, we have:
$$s-\frac{1}{n}\lt x_{n}\le s,\forall n\in \mathbb{N},$$

$\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_{n} = s$